# How to display ToC without the dots and the page numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to print a lightweight version of my ToC : without the dots and without the page index numbers. I've already tried with `tocloft` package and so on, but nothing works.

How can I achieve that ?

I'm using the `report` document class.

Thanks

Comment: I've already tried the solution they propose, but it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tocloft` provides all means for this:

- The dots in the number lines can be switched off using a large `dotsep` value of, say, 10000 or `\cftnodots`, meaning a huge distance between the dots
  This is done by `\newcommand{\cftsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}` etc. for each structure level, i.e. `subsection` etc.
- The page numbers can be switched off using `\cftpagenumbersoff{section}`, as well, for each structure level separately.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cftsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
\newcommand{\cftsubsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
\newcommand{\cftsubsubsectiondotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsubsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]